# Validations for primefaces input element

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How to write validations for primefaces input element as follows

1. Allows combination of numbers and characters.
2. Allow only characters.
3. Doesn't allow only numbers

Please help me, how to add validators to the input element

Comment: You can look into input mask http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/inputMask.jsf

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like @PrasadKharkar write but also you can use validator for this. Here you have tutorial how tom make your own vlidation:

[Mkyong validation tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-validator-in-jsf-2-0/)